# hyperledger fabric not starting every time I have started

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

every time i have run got this error
2018-11-07 11:42:00.480 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 021 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory

steps i have follow

cd /c/users/dasha
./fabric-dev-servers/startFabric.sh

Please help

Comment: error log in container

Comment: 2018-11-07 11:42:00.479 UTC [bccsp] initBCCSP -> DEBU 01f Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2018-11-07 11:42:00.480 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts
2018-11-07 11:42:00.480 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 021 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory

Comment: Where did you get the startFabric.sh script?

Comment: from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/write_first_app.html

Comment: Looks like you are using Windows?  Which version and which version of Docker?